# Hide Current Store from link in store switch in multi store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, ce-1.9.1.0, switcher

I am facing one problem of multi-store option. Both stores are showing but I want to hide the current store and only show the other stores.

These two options are showing at top left side.

Store URL: www.image.pk

Magento 1.9.1.0 version

- If we are in Export Leftovers than only polo republica show.
- if we are in polo republica than only export leftovers shows.

code for un-order List style:

```
<ul class="store-selector-ul">
<?php foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_group['home_url'];?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_group['name']);?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below one:

```
<ul class="store-selector-ul">
    <?php foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
        <?php if($_group->getId() != Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $_group['home_url'];?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_group['name']);?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.This code is not tested but, I hope it will work :

```
<ul class="store-selector-ul">
<?php foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
<?php $_selected = ($_group->getId()==$this->getCurrentGroupId()) ? 'hide' : 'show' ?>
<?php if($_selected == 'show') { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $_group['home_url'];?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_group['name']);?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```